# Cannot select the below option when set menuPortalTarget to document.body in version react-select 2.0.0

Tags: react-select

`<Select
    defaultValue={colourOptions[0]}
    isClearable
    styles={{ menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
    menuPortalTarget={document.body}
    isSearchable
    name="color"
    menuPosition={isFixed ? 'fixed' : 'absolute'}`enter code here
    `menuPlacement={portalPlacement}
    options={colourOptions}
/>`

Just run the 'MenuPortal' example.
Set position to 'fixed', and adjust the viewport's size. The option below cannot be displayed. Look at the picture. How to resolve it? Thanks in advance! [image]